# How would I add echoing table headers to my current code?

Tags: php, html

How would I add echoing table headers to my current code?

I'm a little lost on how to do it because $lines[0] only prints my header row yet when I do an if statement to echo `<th>` if $lines[0] else echo `<tr>` it echos out with multiple empty `<th>`'s so I'm a little lost if anyone could help.

```
function schedule_gen()
{
    //set file
    $filename='schedule.txt';
    //open
    $handler=fopen('schedule.txt','r');
    //read through file
    $file=fread($handler,filesize($filename));

    //start table creation
    echo "<table id='schedule_table'>"; 

    //split into array by return\linefeed
    $lines=explode("\r\n",$file);

    //loop through rows
    for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++) 
    { 
        //if not blank then print row
        if($lines[$i]!=""&&$lines[$i]!=" ")
        {

            echo "<tr class='schedule_row'>"; 

            //split into array by commas
            $items=explode("\t",$lines[$i]);
            //loop through cells 
            for($j=0;$j<count($items);$j++) 
            { 
                 //if not blank then print cell
                 if($items[$j]!=""&&$items[$j]!=" ")
                 {
                     echo "<td class='schedule_cell'>".$items[$j]."</td>"; 
                 }
            } 
            echo "</tr>"; 
        }
     } 
     echo "</table>"; 
     //end table creation

     fclose($handle);
     //close file 
}
```

Example of schedule.txt:

```
Employee/schedule restrictions  Thur 4/26   Fri 4/27    Sat 4/28    Sun 4/29    Mon 4/30    Tue 5/1 Wed 5/2
Administrative                          
Assistant   8a-4    8a-4    no  no  8a-4p   8a-4p   8a-4p

QC Team -Manager                            
QC team / no Tues or Sat    8a-4    8a-4    no  8a-4p   8a-4p   no  8a-4p
QC team 6p-2a   6p-2a   6p-2a   no  6p-2a   6p-2a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure if I read your question right but is this what you need?

```
function schedule_gen()
{
//set file
$filename='schedule.txt';
//open
$handler=fopen('schedule.txt','r');
//read through file
$file=fread($handler,filesize($filename));

//start table creation
echo "<table id='schedule_table'>"; 

//split into array by return\linefeed
$lines=explode("\r\n",$file);

//loop through rows
for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++) 
{ 
//if not blank then print row
if($lines[$i]!=""&&$lines[$i]!=" ")
{
$t_type="td";
if($i==0){$t_type="th";}

//split into array by commas
$items=explode("\t",$lines[$i]);
//loop through cells 
for($j=0;$j<count($items);$j++) 
{ 
//if not blank then print cell
if($items[$j]!=""&&$items[$j]!=" ")
{
echo "<$t_type class='schedule_cell'>".$items[$j]."</$t_type>"; 
}
} 
echo "</tr>"; 
}
} 
echo "</table>"; 
//end table creation

fclose($handle);
//close file 
}
```

Comment: Oh ok I see what my issue was, derp, I was replacing TR with TH and not TD with TH.